# Choose an Apple Silicon machine as the agent to run the Azure pipeline

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to create an Azure pipeline for my Flutter tests. Some of the tests include golden images that were generated on Apple Silicon machines. Therefore, I need the agent running the pipeline to be an Apple Silicon VM.

I am trying to run this on a [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and not a self-hosted agent.

This is my `pipeline.yaml` file:

```yaml
trigger: none

pr: none

jobs:
- job: flutter_test
  displayName: Flutter test
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macos-latest'
  steps:
  - task: FlutterInstall@0
    inputs:
      mode: "auto"
      channel: "stable"
      version: "custom"
      customVersion: "3.7.12"
  - script: flutter pub get
    displayName: Install dependencies
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  - script: flutter test
    displayName: Run tests
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance  !!!